# how to yii getPost for array _POST vars?

Tags: php, yii, http-post

Assuming i have

```
$_POST["x"]["y"] = 5;
```

how can i

```
Yii::app()->request->getPost('x[y]');
```

how can i retrieve the post variable by index ?
and is there any yii function that checks for sql injection ? does the getPost do that check ?

Thank you .

Comment: I am not familiar with yii, but couldnt you do Yii::app()->request->getPost('x')['y']? (Note this only works with 5.4, if < 5.4 you will need to do $x = Yii::app()->request->getPost('x'); $val = $x['y']

Comment: i don't think sql injection prevention will be performed this way if the function getPost cleans the var from injectors ?

Comment: Like I said I am not familiar with yii, but I am pretty certain that the getPost function will not prevent sql injection. Looks like the source code for this function is https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php and it does nothing for sql injection. Read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/#hh11 for how to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am not familiar with yii, but looking at the source code for the function 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php

You would do

```
$x = Yii::app()->request->getPost('x');
$y = $x['y'];
```

The getPost function WILL NOT prevent sql injection. Please read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/#hh11 for more information on securing your yii application

Comment: BTW if you need to get value from $_GET array you need to write `$x = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('x');`

Answer (score 10):

**Yii2**

```
$x = Yii::$app->request->post('x');
```

Comment: $x = Yii::app()->request->post('x');
$y = $x['y'];

Answer (score 2):

With model Test it's look like this

```
$test = new Test();
$test->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('x');   
$y = $test->getAttribute('y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yii::app()->request->getParam('delete');

you can see this link

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28547-get-post-parameters-with-the-same-name/

Answer (score -1):

```
> My controller 
>     public function mi(){
>         echo "Hola MI Controlador!";
>         // in login scenario
> 
>         $request = Yii::app()->request->getPost('nombre');
>         print_r($request);
> 
> 
>         //$this->render('index',array('nombre',$post));
>     }
```

Comment: To post data is obbligatory use a model if i dont use a db??? the post dont workk help me please!                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                 In laravel in a controller you can use this public function mi(request){ var_dump($request) }; But in yii I dont understand the logic ! is different and on guide there arent many solution thanks for your attention! yii group