# Passing variable from javascript to PHP using ajax in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I want to pass variable from javascript to php using POST and I am doing something like the following. I view1.php

```
 <script>
function testing(col) {
    $("#bookId").val(col);
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: <?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('siteaccess/create') ?>,
            data: {ad_id:<?php echo "hello" ?>},
            success: function(col){console.log(col)},
    });
}
</script>
```

In same file I have following code calling testing()

```
function(){
testing($(this).parent().parent().children(\':nth-child(2)\').text());
 }
```

In create.php I have

```
<?php 
$v = $_POST['ad_id'];
echo $v;
?>
```

For create.php I am getting this error "Undefined index: ad_id". Can anyone guide where I am making mistake?

Comment: at .ajax you haven't escaped your url: '<php>' and you should define dataType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the semicolumn in the php code and also define the dataType in the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('siteaccess/create'); ?>",
        data: {"ad_id":"<?php echo 'hello'; ?>"},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(col){console.log(col)},
});
```

use the above code.

Comment: @Svetlio right now i have done. same for the data value also.

Comment: No I had already tried semicolon, colon, inverted commas almost everything but it is giving same error "Undefined index: ad_id"

Comment: yes I copied your code to my file but it is giving same error.

Comment: @user2673943 you cann't get the data directly on the view page you need to get the data on controller's action then send it to view page. may be this is the issue. see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301639/how-to-yii-getpost-for-array-post-vars

Comment: ok I tried that also I changed $_POST to Yii::app()->request->getPost('ad_id'); Now no error is shown but when I echo Yii::app()->request->getPost('ad_id'); nothing is displayed.

Comment: @user2673943 well you are going correct where you have written this. write it in the controller's action where you are hitting the url.

Comment: ok now it is working. I started debugging using firebug and it was showing error "bad request" for post method due to csrf validation failed. I had enabled csrfvalidation due to which POST was not working. After I had disabled it was working. But why isn't the message is displayed on page even POST request is successfull according to firebug. According to my code I am doing echo $_POST['ad_id'] but nothing shown on webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Neither your URL or `ad_id` contain quotes so it won't work. Try this:

```
<script>
function testing(col) {
    $("#bookId").val(col);
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('siteaccess/create') ?>",
            data: {ad_id:"<?php echo "hello" ?>"},
            success: function(col){console.log(col)},
    });
}
</script>
```