# trouble submitting ajax form in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am creating a widget for use in a website to 'find' a match in any field in the database. I currently am using a jQuery 'Dialog' box, and wish to submit the form, have the form redirect to a controller/action (I am using yii which uses the MCV model), and return the output of that function into the current window.

I am currently using a hidden div, and the jquery load function.

```
$("#find_results").load(loadPage, function(){
}).show();
```

which calls a function that does this essentially:

```
public function actionFind(){
    if (!empty($_POST)){
       //do really big query
       //put results into <tr> and <td> tags using a for loop
    }else{
       echo <tr><td>"no results found"</td></tr>;
    }
}
```

this code returns an output, but only ever "no results found", leading me to believe that the form never actually gets posted.

does anyone know what kind of black magic is happening here??

thanks!

P.S.

The dialog box is a partial view which contains the form to be submitted with the action /controller/find

updated:

I implemented this instead: new error is "undefined index: findtext", which is the name of my text input.

```
$("#find_results").load(loadPage,{ data: $("#find_form").serialize() },function(data){
         console.log(data);
         $('#find_results').html(data);
         $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: "*I am creating a widget for use in a website to 'find' a match in any field in the database.*" be very careful that you dont unwittingly expose details about your database schema to potential attackers. A feature like this could be quite dangerous ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets look at the [signature for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
>
> **url**
>
> Type: String
>
> A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> **data**
>
> Type: PlainObject or String
>
> A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>
> **complete**
>
> Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

So, if you want to send data to the server, you'd do something like:

```
$("#find_results").load(loadPage, {someKey: 'some value'}, function(){
          $(this).show();
});
```

Now, that we are sending data, nevermind what I said before about `$_GET`

From [the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Request Method
>
> The POST method is used *if data is provided as an object*; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Also, since you've tagged `yii` you may need to access `$_POST` differently in your app, something like this:

```
public function actionFind( ){ // pass in $request from your app
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if (!empty( $request->post() )){ // change this
       //do really big query
       //put results into <tr> and <td> tags using a for loop
    }else{
       echo <tr><td>"no results found"</td></tr>;
    }
}
```

---

**See [The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html) which says this:**

```
$request = Yii::$app->request; 
$post = $request->post();
// equivalent to: $post = $_POST;

$id = $request->post('id');
// equivalent to: $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
```

Comment: hmm, I tried changing it to get but it's still not being submitted, do I have to chain this somehow so it'll submit and then get? I think what I'm doing here is simply redirecting using AJAX and loading in the page, but since the form never seems to have been submitted in the first place it just skips over the section of code containing my query,

Comment: Where exactly do you call `actionFind()`? Also, if you put `var_dump($_GET)` right before `if (!empty($_GET))`, what is the response?

Comment: @Andy since you're using `yii`, please see my update above

Comment: var_dump returns array(0) { }

Comment: and actionFind is a function in the controller so it is attached to the form's 'action' attribute.

Comment: @Andy did you see my `yii` update? Does it work with `$request->get()`?

Comment: I did, just tried that as well, it doesn't recognize request as a variable, I am currently using an older version of Yii, I believe that's why.

Comment: Also, using a straight $('#find_form').submit() actually does return query data successfully, it just goes to a different page. by the way, thank you for all your support so far!

Comment: On the page I linked to, they define `$request` like this `$request = Yii::$app->request;`  Do you have something similar in your app? Since this is a function, you'd actually need to pass in `$request` from elsewhere

Comment: Wait, are you actually submitting some data to the page from the form? Or trying to anyway?

Comment: Correct, I am trying to submit data from the form inside the dialog box, redirect to the controller action, and then populate another field of the dialog box with the results of the query.

Comment: @Andy , see my update, ive not used `yii` so Im not sure what the differences in versions are. You may not need the `$request` bit in your version. But have a look at the `.load()` changes, if you are wanting to send data, that may be your issue

Comment: see my changes above. $request doesn't seem to be in my version of Yii, so I'm still using $_POST. I attempted to pass the data through serialized, though findtext returns a value when I print it to console, it seems to not have one according to the callback value, which I find to be strange.

Comment: What do you get if you call `console.log($("#find_form").serialize());` just before the call to `.load()`?

Comment: I used "testing find" as my input text, this was the output:
findtext=testing+find

Comment: See my update, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12302168/1376624),  `$request = Yii::$app->request;` should work

Comment: what version of yii are you using?

Comment: update, that does work! doesn't register as being posted still but strangely, when I use that and then do a var_dump[$_POST] it gives me actual post values. (even stranger is that I do a var dump before I do any of this.

I am using yii 1.1.6